# How come this guy be able to comment?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today I just got a critic comment on my [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11650/do-the-scientific-miracles-in-the-quran-actually-exist/11651?noredirect=1#comment25398_11651) by a [user](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/5434/user5434) whose Rep is only 1. Having 1 rep doesn't allow a user to comment.

What was this then a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope it isn't a bug. It was a comment by the user posted incorrectly as an answer, mostly because of lack of privilege to comment.

So I choose to convert it into a comment, using the moderator tools, on your post instead of deleting it.

Comment: It's not a good Idea to work around the system, If it was not allowed for users with 1rep to comment we should let that be so

Comment: It was meant to be comment in the first place on that answer so it was probably the right thing to do. However he won't be able to comment again if the OP answers his queries.

Comment: Ah, now I get it! :-) Thanks :)